# How to change folder that I'm sending data to on mongoDB Atlas?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, atlas

I'm creating MERN stack app.
I've already created one and connected it to mongoDB Atlas cluster and everything works fine but everything has gone to "test" folder.
So I'm creating another app, and want it to go to another folder, so my question is how can I define where I want my data to be stored? I created a folder, but I don't know how to direct data to go there.

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you share your connection uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That folder is a database in MongoDB. I'm sure you have `/test` in your connection URI string. You can specify there the database you want to create in another app. If there is no db specify, mongo will try to authenticate you to `/admin` database.

[MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/) for reference.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I was trying to find where is the word "test" but I couldn't find it in any of my files. But, I have figured out that if you don't put anything in your URI string, it will be "test" by default so my URI was this: MONGO = mongodb+srv://name:<password>@<name>.mongodb.net/{there should be a specific route but it was empty for me}?retryWrites=true&w=majority

So it is the solution

btw thanks for the answer anyways! <3